# Как сделать ограничение в form?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма на уменьшение и увеличение числа. Но не могу понять как сделать ограничение до 1, чтобы значение не уходило в отрицательные значения?

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" id="minus" value="-" onClick="textb.value = (textb.value-1)">
  <input type="number" min="1" required id="textb" name="name" value="1" />
  <input type="button" value="+" onClick="textb.value = (+textb.value+1)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Кнопками вы обходите ограничение от `input`. Для того, чтобы избавиться от этой проблемы, проверяйте значение при клике:

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" id="minus" value="-" onClick="textb.value = (textb.value-1 > 1 ? textb.value-1 : 1)">
  <input type="number" min="1" required id="textb" name="name" value="1" />
  <input type="button" value="+" onClick="textb.value = (+textb.value+1)">
</form>
```

Comment: Или `textb.value = Math.max(1, textb.value - 1);`

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!

Comment: @АндрейКурусь В таком случае пометьте вопрос решенным)